# Check if div element value is same with object inside a constant

Tags: html, jquery, css

This is about body mass index classification and each bmi grade have a suggest diet.

How can I create a function whether the div element is same with constant's object, while the constant have multiple object. If the element inside div is same as specific constant's object, then toggleClass(). I tried to use a if else and is() function but it doesn't work. The example is below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

     const grade = {
        "underweight": "underweight",
        "healthy": "healthy",
        "overweight": "overweight",
        "obese": "obesity",
        "obeseI": "obese Grade I",
        "obeseII": "obese Grade II",
        "obeseIII": "obese Grade III"
    };
    if ($(".Classification").is(grade.underweight)){
            $(".underweight").toggleClass('show');

    }   else if ($(".Classification").is(grade.normalweight)){
            $(".normalweight").toggleClass('show');

    }   else if ($(".Classification").is(grade.overweight)){
            $(".overweight").toggleClass('show');

    }   else if ($(".Classification").is(grade.obese)){
            $(".overweight").toggleClass('show');

    }   else if ($(".Classification").is(grade.obeseI)){
            $(".overweight").toggleClass('show');

    }   else if ($(".Classification").is(grade.obeseII)){
            $(".overweight").toggleClass('show');
            
    }   else if ($(".Classification").is(grade.obeseIII)){
            $(".overweight").toggleClass('show');

    }   else {
            $(".underweight").toggleClass('hide');
            $(".normalweight").toggleClass('hide');
            $(".overweight").toggleClass('hide');
    }


});
```

```css
.underweight, .normalweight, .overweight{
    display: none;
}
.show{
    display: block;
}
.hide{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="gred">
     <span>You are classified as</span>
     <span class="Classification">unknown</span>
</div>

<div class="breakfast">
    <div class="title"><i class="fas fa-bread-slice"></i> Breakfast</div>
    <ul class="underweight">
        <li>2 sandwich</li>
        <li>Green chutney</li>
        <li>1 cup milk</li>
        <li>3 cashews</li>
        <li>4 almonds</li>
        <li>2 walnuts</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="normalweight">
        <li>1.5c whole grain</li>
        <li>1/8 cup walnuts</li>
        <li>1 packet Stevia</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="overweight">
        <li>3 egg whites</li>
        <li>1 toasted bread</li>
        <li>1/2 low fat milk</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="lunch">
    <div class="title"><i class="fas fa-pizza-slice"></i> Lunch</div>
    <ul class="underweight">
        <li>1 cup arhar dal</li>
        <li>1 cup potato curry</li>
        <li>3 chapatti</li>
        <li>1/2 cup rice</li>
        <li>1/2 cup low fat curd</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="normalweight">
        <li>Sunshine salad</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="overweight">
        <li>1 cup arhar dal</li>
        <li>1 chapatti</li>
        <li>1/2 low fat curd</li>
        <li>salad</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="dinner">
    <div class="title"><i class="fas fa-fish"></i> Dinner</div>
    <ul class="underweight">
        <li>1.5 cup chicken curry</li>
        <li>3 chapatti</li>
        <li>Salad</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="normalweight">
        <li>Baked buffalo wings</li>
        <li>5 stalks celery</li>
        <li>2T light bleu cheese dressing</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="overweight">
        <li>1 cup pumpkin</li>
        <li>1 chapatti</li>
        <li>Salad</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is .Classification defined ? Please be articulate with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few problems with the code. `.is()` is not the same as `===`. You are doing string comparisons, so you need to be using `===`.
Also, the classes were not necessary. jQuery comes with a prebuilt `show()` and `hide()` that take care of that for you. Plus, using `toggleClass` like this can be problematic when all you really want to do is either show it or hide it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      const grade = {
        "underweight": "underweight",
        "healthy": "healthy",
        "overweight": "overweight",
        "obese": "obesity",
        "obeseI": "obese Grade I",
        "obeseII": "obese Grade II",
        "obeseIII": "obese Grade III"
      };      
      $(".underweight, .normalweight, .overweight").hide(); // hide everything to start
      let c = $(".Classification").text().trim(); // get the text in the .Classification span
      if (c !== 'underweight' && c !== 'normalweight') c = 'overweight'; // if its not underweight or normalweight it's considered overweight
      c = `.${c}`; // turn it into a className
      if ($(c).length > 0) $(c).show() // if the classname exists (like .underweight) show it
    });
```

**Example with buttons for testing**

In the example below, I added buttons so you could see how the layout changes depending on the classification.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const grade = {
    "underweight": "underweight",
    "healthy": "healthy",
    "overweight": "overweight",
    "obese": "obesity",
    "obeseI": "obese Grade I",
    "obeseII": "obese Grade II",
    "obeseIII": "obese Grade III"
  };
  populateMenu();
})

function populateMenu() {
  $(".underweight, .normalweight, .overweight").hide(); // hide everything to start
  let c = $(".Classification").text().trim(); // get the text in the .Classification span
  if (c !== 'underweight' && c !== 'normalweight') c = 'overweight'; // if its not underweight or normalweight it's considered overweight
  c = `.${c}`; // turn it into a className
  if ($(c).length > 0) $(c).show() // if the classname exists (like .underweight) show it
};

// development function, can be removed
function changeto(v) {
  $(".Classification").text(v);
  populateMenu()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gred">
  <span>You are classified as</span>
  <span class="Classification">unknown</span>
</div>

<!-- Development only for testing - can be removed -->
<div>
  Change to <button onclick='changeto("underweight")'>underweight</button> <button onclick='changeto("normalweight")'>normalweight</button> <button onclick='changeto("overweight")'>overweight</button>
</div>

<div class="breakfast">
  <div class="title"><i class="fas fa-bread-slice"></i> Breakfast</div>
  <ul class="underweight">
    <li>2 sandwich</li>
    <li>Green chutney</li>
    <li>1 cup milk</li>
    <li>3 cashews</li>
    <li>4 almonds</li>
    <li>2 walnuts</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="normalweight">
    <li>1.5c whole grain</li>
    <li>1/8 cup walnuts</li>
    <li>1 packet Stevia</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="overweight">
    <li>3 egg whites</li>
    <li>1 toasted bread</li>
    <li>1/2 low fat milk</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="lunch">
  <div class="title"><i class="fas fa-pizza-slice"></i> Lunch</div>
  <ul class="underweight">
    <li>1 cup arhar dal</li>
    <li>1 cup potato curry</li>
    <li>3 chapatti</li>
    <li>1/2 cup rice</li>
    <li>1/2 cup low fat curd</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="normalweight">
    <li>Sunshine salad</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="overweight">
    <li>1 cup arhar dal</li>
    <li>1 chapatti</li>
    <li>1/2 low fat curd</li>
    <li>salad</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="dinner">
  <div class="title"><i class="fas fa-fish"></i> Dinner</div>
  <ul class="underweight">
    <li>1.5 cup chicken curry</li>
    <li>3 chapatti</li>
    <li>Salad</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="normalweight">
    <li>Baked buffalo wings</li>
    <li>5 stalks celery</li>
    <li>2T light bleu cheese dressing</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="overweight">
    <li>1 cup pumpkin</li>
    <li>1 chapatti</li>
    <li>Salad</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: May I know what is the function of populateMenu( ) ?

Comment: I updated my answer to NOT have that. The reason I put that in was for the testable snippet. In order to show how the layout changed depending on the classification, I had to move the logic out of the document.ready function, and in doing so I had to put it in it's own function. It was just to show an example. I updated my answer to have the code at the top you need for the javascript

Comment: @Innerout - did this end up working for you?

Comment: Wonderful! Please mark as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

is .Classification a div which has the value representing a grade?

something like this, I presume:

```
<div class="Classification">underweight</div>
```

if that is the case, I believe you must access the text content inside of that div, and not only select it as an object.

```
    if ($(".Classification").text().is(grade.underweight)){
          $(".underweight").toggleClass('show');
```

try it with one statement and let's see what happens.